# Wordpress: My site has a error "Currently unable to handle this request"

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, request

I created a website in wordpress that I edited in localhost, then when I transferred it to a live site (online site) using FTP. I got a error when accessing online.

> The www.quattourbags.com page isn’t working
>
> www.quattourbags.com is currently unable to handle this request.

In my **error_log:**

```
[18-Apr-2016 20:29:35 Asia/Manila] PHP Warning:  require(/home/quattour/public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/quattour/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21

[18-Apr-2016 20:29:35 Asia/Manila] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/quattour/public_html/wp-includes/load.php' 

[18-Apr-2016 13:08:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/quattour/public_html/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/quattour/public_html/wp-includes/compat.php on line 338

/home/quattour/public_html/wp-includes/compat.php on line 338
[18-Apr-2016 13:21:14 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in /home/quattour/public_html/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/inc/jetpack.php on line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

> [18-Apr-2016 20:29:35 Asia/Manila] PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed
>   opening required '/home/quattour/public_html/wp-includes/load.php'

Indicates that one of the required files are missing.